# What if Schrödinger's cat's meowed?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, observables, schroedingers-cat

Sorry if this has been asked (every similar question has a title that basically tags Schrödinger's cat)

If after the superposition of the cat being dead and alive at one time was created, and the person outside the box heard a meow- would the superposition be lost and the cat be 100% alive?

Comment: A cat could not meow in the first place if it was in a superposition. Good luck performing the biochemical processes necessary for life without quantum decoherence.

Comment: If I were sitting in a box for a few years, you wouldn't know if I were dead or alive. But I _can_ make a sound to let everyone know that I am.

Comment: What's the *point* of the box if the inside is observable from the outside? You might as well give it transparent sides. You might as well run a wire from the Geiger counter (that really does the observation/irreversible-collapse) to the outside.

Comment: It is a postulate of the gendanken experiment that *prevents observation* of the internal system. That postulate is not restricted to visual observation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the superposition state of 'dead and alive' would then be projected onto the 'alive' state because in a way the person measures 'alive'. I assume the cat won't meow if it were dead. The quantum system  (the cat) will be in contact with the outside world and as a result decoherence will erase all quantum behavior.